# Bad Operand types for binary operator '/' first type String second type int

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, javabeans

New to javabeans so please forgive me if this is simplistic:

Getting this error while writing a javabean page. The code basically asked to add 7 values together and then divide the total by 160. Code is:

```
public String getAverage(){
return (Str1 + Str2 + Str3 + Str4 + Str5+ Str6+ Str7) / (160);
                 add 7 values and then divide answer by 160.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this instead:

```
public double getAverage(){        
    String[] inputs = new String[]{Str1, Str2, Str3, Str4, Str5, Str6, Str7};
    int sum = 0;
    for (String input : inputs) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(input);
    }      
    return sum / 160d;
}
```

Things to consider:

- You should return a `double` from the method if you're calculating an average from a list of `int` values
- You cannot add `String`s together the way you've suggested; you need to convert them to `int`s before the addition
- Variable names in Java should start with a lower-case letter (`str1`, `str2` instead of `Str1`, `Str2`).
- You should minimize the scope of variables; in your example, `Str1...Str7` are global variables, which makes it harder to track where they might get modified. Consider passing in the inputs as an argument to the method by declaring the signature like this:

  ```
  public double getAverage(String... inputs)
  ```